# Vue3 onMounted function doesn’t work in esm package bundled with rollup

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, rollup

I bundled a vue3 component with rollup. The component is simple:

```
// main.vue
<template>
  <div>
    <div @click="clickDiv">{{ 1 }}</div>
    <div ref="divRef"></div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import { onMounted, ref, defineComponent } from 'vue'
export default defineComponent({
  name: 'Vue3Component',
  mounted () {
    console.log('component mounted') // it works well
  },
  setup() {
    const divRef = ref()
    const clickDiv = () => {
      console.log('divRef', divRef) // it causes some warnings
    }
    onMounted(() => {
      console.log('component onMounted') // it causes some warnings
    })
    return {
      a: ref(1),
      clickDiv,
      divRef
    }
  },
})
</script>
```

and the input entry:

```
// index.js
import Vue3Component from './main.vue'
Vue3Component.install = (app) => {
  app.component(Vue3Component.name, Vue3Component)
}

export {
  Vue3Component
}
```

rollup config code:

```
// rollup.config.js
import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve'
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs'
import pkg from './package.json'
import external from 'rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external'
import vuePlugin from 'rollup-plugin-vue'

const extensions = ['.vue', '.js']

const globals = {
  vue: 'Vue',
  'highlight.js': 'hljs',
  'marked': 'marked'
}

export default [
  {
    input: 'src/index.js',
    output: [
      {
        name: 'VueNextMEditor',
        file: pkg.main,
        format: 'umd',
        globals
      },
      {
        file: pkg.module,
        format: 'es'
      },
      {
        name: 'VueNextMEditor',
        file: pkg.unpkg,
        format: 'umd',
        plugins: [terser()],
        globals
      }
    ],
    plugins: [
      external(),
      vuePlugin(),
      resolve(),
      commonjs({ extensions })
    ]
  }
]
```

When i test the component  locally with vue-cli, the `onMounted` in setup doesn't works. The browser shows error like this:

```
[Vue warn]: onMounted is called when there is no active component instance to be associated with. Lifecycle injection APIs can only be used during execution of setup(). If you are using async setup(), make sure to register lifecycle hooks before the first await statement.
```

```
[Vue warn]: Missing ref owner context. ref cannot be used on hoisted vnodes. A vnode with ref must be created inside the render function. 
  at <Vue3Component> 
  at <App>
```

But `mounted` outside the setup function works will.
Anyone can help me to resolve this problem?
[Vue3Component](https://github.com/hellomrbigshot/Vue3Component)

Comment: Show your Vue CLI code that uses the component.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it apparently happens when you install Vue twice.

For the record, I had the same error as you:

```html
Missing ref owner context. ref cannot be used on hoisted vnodes. A vnode with ref must be created inside the render function.
```

But in my case it is because I was using a homemade Vue library in my Vue app, and in the build definition of the lib (`vite.config.js`), I did not place correctly this option to avoid bundling Vue in the lib:

```js
external: ['vue'],
```

I placed it directly under `build` and not under `rollupOptions`as specified per Vite doc: https://vitejs.dev/guide/build.html#library-mode

That was tricky to find! I would like a better error message from Vue because this was cryptic!

Comment: This is the correct answer. The message of hoisted vnode values are misleading. 

The problem is with the fact that both - the project, which will use the package, and the package itself, has 2 occurrences of Vue. 

The resolution already provided by Damien - remove the Vue from bundled package by adding `external: ['vue'],` to `vite.config.js` as follows: 

`export default defineConfig({ build: { rollupOptions: { external: ['vue'] } });`

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the problem. It happenes because I install `vue` twice. I resolved it with `pnpm link`

```
$ cd vue3-component
$ pnpm install

$ cd example
$ pnpm link ../node_modules/vue
$ pnpm install
$ pnpm serve
```

It works!